# How do you create objects of another class from a .csv file?

Tags: java

Im working on a task that requires me to read from a .csv file using stream API, go over each line and construct an object with the lines. The object class is called Planet and is:

```
public Planet(String name, long inhabitants, boolean stargateAvailable, boolean dhdAvailable, List<String> teamsVisited) {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public long getInhabitants() {
    return inhabitants;
}

public boolean isStargateAvailable() {
    return stargateAvailable;
}

public boolean isDhdAvailable() {
    return dhdAvailable;
}

public List<String> getTeamsVisited() {
    return teamsVisited;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

[image: This is the .cvs file.]

So using stream API to go over each of the lines of the .cvs file i need to create objects of class Planet.

I havent made any progress at all because I really am not sure how to use stream API

```
public class Space {

     public List<Planet> csvDataToPlanets(String filePath) {
         return null;
     }
```

Comment: If you've already tried something please share the code with us as well. E.g how you read the lines etc.

Comment: Screenshotting the csv is a bad idea, just copy-paste a sample. That is so that people can potentially use it as test data. That being said, it doesn't sound like you did much research, how about you read up on the stream API before asking for help? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Comment: 1. Use stream API to read the file. 2. For each line read construct the object using Reflection API something like this:  final Planet p = Planet.class.getConstructor(arg1, arg2, . . . ).newInstance(arg1, arg2, arg3, . . . .);

Answer (score 0):

try the below snippet.

```
 File inputF = new File(inputFilePath);
  InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS));
  // skip the header of the csv
  inputList = br.lines().skip(1).map(mapToItem).collect(Collectors.toList());
  br.close();
```

For more information check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-read-a-big-csv-file-with-java-8-and-stream)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String fileName = "<Your File Path"";

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        stream.forEach(<Method to split the string based with ',' as delimiter and call Constructor using Reflection API>);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```